# Getting Window Position and Size in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ui-automation

I am looking for a way to get the current size and position of a window by using PowerShell. I am currently using the UIAutomation (https://uiautomation.codeplex.com/) package to do some other window manipulation so if anyone happens to know how to do it through PowerShell either with or without that package, I would be very interested to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show some code? It's possible to get any window's size and position in many ways. Particularly if you have the handle to the Window in question.

Comment: Get-UIAWindow -ProcessId ($PID).Id -AutomationId $autoID
<--------------
Using that code snippet, I am able to select the main window to the application I am working with using the UIAutomation package.

Comment: Is that object able to provide additional attributes? I don't use UIAutomation

Comment: I looked through the different properties of the Get-UIAWindow and I think I found what I was looking for. The following will return a lot of data about the window for a Notepad.exe app:
 $test = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru | Get-UiaWindow #| Get-UiaCurrentPattern -PassThru
$test.Current.BoundingRectangle <----- Just put a line break between '-PassThru' and '$test.Current.BoundingRectange'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get-UIAWindow seems to have some additional properties that I didn't know were there. Using the BoundingRectange property, I was able to get all of the details about the window position, size, as well as the relative position.

The following will return a lot of data about the window for a Notepad.exe app:

```
$test = Start-Process notepad.exe -PassThru | Get-UiaWindow #| Get-UiaCurrentPattern -PassThru<br/>

$test.Current.BoundingRectangle
```